# SQL Server Update a column character on the fly

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a DB table that has a column called `Pools`, the programmer made an error and has the data as so:

```
pool1,pool2;pool3;pool4
```

I need to update every row in the table, and just replace the same data back in except `replace(column, ',', ';')`. Replace the commas in a given column in a row with semi-colons.

Any thoughts?

Comment: didn't you answer your own question? update table set Pools = REPLACE(Pools ,',',';'); same as what you have?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
update YourTable set
  Pools = replace(Pools, ',', ';')
```

Comment: OK that was simple, I did not think it was that simple. I am so used to perl based DB work. Thanks for the education.